# Offering purchase an app or in-app-purchase with monero

Tags: programming-languages

I would like to offer a paid app in the traditional platforms with the option to pay it or the plugins in monero. How can I code this?

Answer (score 2):

For in app purchases you could use [Monero Integrations](https://github.com/monero-integrations) or BTCPayServer with Monero plugin as your payment gateway or some of the various custodial solutions, however Apple's and Google's walled gardens not necessarily allow payments outside their own solutions, so you might need to distribute your app yourself or some alternative App Store like F-Droid.

However, you might offer some kind of subscription model like VPN apps do and identify your users by some kind of login system and sell your subscriptions for Monero outside the official app stores and their payment options.